# Send a single raw keystroke to ansi-term

Tags: spacemacs, ansi-term

Occasionally, I want to send a keystroke to a program in my `ansi-term` buffer that is already mapped to something in emacs.  I know that for one I use often I could change my configuration to always send it, but in this case I just need a one-off.

Is there any way I can set some key combination to "send the next key as raw" ?

Comment: Most characters are sent as raw in term char mode, which is the default.  Are you using line mode?  Any reason not to use the default?

Comment: In principle, prefixing the key with `C-q` avoids all keyboard translations. But, I do not know whether this works in your case. E.g., in line-mode you need the final RET to send the input to the terminal.

Comment: I am in char mode, in `evil-insert-mode` under spacemacs.  `C-q C-c` does not seem to send a `C-c` to my terminal for example -- but maybe there is a different key in evil mode?  Nope, `C-q C-c` in hybrid mode doesn't send to the terminal either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
(defun singpolyma/term-insert-literal (key)
    "Take a keypress and insert it literally into a terminal."
    (interactive "cPress key:")
    (term-send-raw-string (format "%c" key))
    )

(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda ()
        (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-`") 'singpolyma/term-insert-literal)
        )
```